# name is not incrementing by 1 after number 45

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, increment

i am trying to add a location name to my output text files.
[image]

As you can see my numbers are incrementing properly. But i have coded like after number 45 i need to reset the number to 1, also the **Carousel:45** should change to ** Carousel1:1**. But it is not happening... why it is not happening. any help please!!!!
My code snippet:

```
  public void just_create_text()
    {
        //Here we are exporting header
        string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
        string CarouselName = enter.Text;
        int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15 };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[0]).Trim();
        string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

        for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
            sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));

        sb.AppendLine("Location".PadRight(15));
        sb.AppendLine();

        int tmpCarousel = 0;
        int carouselNumber = 0;
        Dictionary<string, int> namesForCarousels = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < textfile.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                sb.Append(textfile[i].Cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));

            string name = textfile[i].Cells[1];

            if (namesForCarousels.TryGetValue(name, out tmpCarousel) == false)
            {
                carouselNumber++;
                   if (carouselNumber > 45)
                    carouselNumber = 1;//resetting to number1, but name is
                   //not changing to Carousel1..
                namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber;
            }
            var strCorousel = lstMX.Find(x => x.MAX_PN.Equals(name)).Carousel;
            strCorousel = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCorousel)) ? CarouselName : strCorousel;
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", strCorousel, carouselNumber).PadRight(15));

            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Z:\Desktop\output.TXT", sb.ToString());
    }
```

**OUTPUT i need**

I need after **Carousel**:45 >>> i need Carousel**1:1**. How can i do this..?

Comment: Stacy please step through your code in a debugger and look at what you are doing. The problem is your `lstMX` list does not have the `MAX_PN` you think it does, you do not check for this. We can't tell you what to put in instead because we don't have your data. We have [explained this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805777/) yet you are making random changes to your code in an attempt to make the problem go away. This does not work; use the debugger, find out what is wrong, fix it.

Comment: Please don't simply. down vote.. Whats wrong with my question.. i can't understand you guys.. Thans

Comment: @DourHighArch brother.. this question is entirely different!!! as my name is not incrementing.. from carousel:X to carousel1:XX, once it reaches 45. this is not happening.. thats my question...

Comment: It is not different; your earlier mistake is still there and now you are calling `namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber` after `namesForCarousels.TryGetValue(name, out tmpCarousel) == false`. You test if something does not exist then try to assign to a nonexistent value! The error message will tell you that. Read error messages. Use the debugger.

Comment: @DourHighArch i was sitting with this error for last 5 hours can't get through.. instead of making it more worse  can you give me a solution in answer please.. my full code <http://pastie.org/9704027>

Comment: @Dour High Arch, namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber; does not fail if name is not in the dictionary, it adds it. The set on the indexer works - the get will throw key not found.

Answer (score 1):

You never use the numbers stored in your dictionary `namesForCarousels` after setting them.  Probably you want

```
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", strCorousel, namesForCarousels[name]).PadRight(15));
```

Also, you should rename `carouselNumber` to something like `carouselNumberCounter`.  It's not the number of the current carousel, it's a counter used to assign a number to the *next* carousel.  And for additional clarity, get rid of the local variable `tmpCarousel` and do:

```
    if (!namesForCarousels.ContainsKey(name))
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to follow your code if you use more descriptive variable names. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but I assume you want to re-use the same carousel number for a given "Max Pn" if you've already allocated it - at the moment, you populate that mapping but you don't use it, you are reliant on max pn being in order. I don't actually see why carousel number wouldn't reset, but if you tidy it up perhaps you have a better chance of seeing what is happening.

Also given your null reference exception from your other question, this protects against that - though it probably indicates another problem elsewhere in the population of your "lstMx".

```
public static void just_create_text()
{
    //Here we are exporting header
    string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
    string defaultCarouselName = enter.Text;

    int[] columnPaddings = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15 };
    StringBuilder completedOutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[0]).Trim();
    string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

    for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
        completedOutputBuilder.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(columnPaddings[c]));

    completedOutputBuilder.AppendLine("Location".PadRight(15));
    completedOutputBuilder.AppendLine();

    int carouselNumberForEntry = 0;
    Dictionary<string, int> maxPnToCarouselNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    for (int i = 0; i < textfile.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
            completedOutputBuilder.Append(_textfile[i].Cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(columnPaddings[c]));

        string maxPnForEntry = textfile[i].Cells[1];

        int previouslyAllocatedCarouselNumberForMaxPn = 0;
        if (maxPnToCarouselNumber.TryGetValue(maxPnForEntry, out previouslyAllocatedCarouselNumberForMaxPn) == false)
        {
            // assign a new courousel number for this max pn
            carouselNumberForEntry++;
            if (carouselNumberForEntry > 45)
                carouselNumberForEntry = 1;
            // for better clarity use add
            maxPnToCarouselNumber.Add(maxPnForEntry, carouselNumberForEntry);
        }
        else
        {                    
            // use the carousel number previous assigned for this maxPn
            carouselNumberForEntry = previouslyAllocatedCarouselNumberForMaxPn;
        }

        // find the related max pn carousel entry (if relatedPn is not found this suggests a problem elsewhere)
        MAX_PN_Carousel relatedPn = lstMx.Find(x => x.MAX_PN != null && x.MAX_PN.Equals(maxPnForEntry, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        // assign the name from the entry, or use the default carousel name if unavailable
        string carouselNameForMaxPn = (relatedPn == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relatedPn.Carousel)) ? defaultCarouselName : relatedPn.Carousel;
        // add the new column in the output
        completedOutputBuilder.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", carouselNameForMaxPn, carouselNumberForEntry).PadRight(15));
        completedOutputBuilder.Append("\r\n");
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\dev\output.TXT", completedOutputBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: output is still the same!!! i need output like this <https://imageshack.com/i/iqjKDPIYp>

Comment: u there... can you have a look to the above attached link

Comment: So is the column in bold to the right is what you are actually getting? So Carousel1:2 instead of Carousel2 for example. If so, the reset from 45 has worked, it is a different problem. How do you expect fetching the MAX_PN carousel to work? If it's never correct it's not in the list, you should throw an exception and fix the population of that list instead. If it is there, what do you want to do with it? In every case at the moment you are post fixing what you get with the carousel number you increment, so you are ending up with Carousel1:2, Carousel1:3 etc.

Comment: Also consider investing some time in this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn